# Perl Debugger: DBD::mysql::db do failed: MySQL server has gone away at

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I use MySQL with the DBI Module for my perl programming database connections.
I got the error message as below when using mysql :

```
Issuing rollback() due to DESTROY without explicit disconnect() of       
DBD::mysql::db handle db=db;ip=X.X.X.X; at /code/save2db.plx line 104.
DBD::mysql::db DESTROY failed: MySQL server has gone away at   
/code/save2db.plx line 104.
    (in cleanup) DBD::mysql::db DESTROY failed: MySQL server has gone away  
at /code/save2db.plx line 104.
```

the line 104 in my code is

```
103    $dbh->disconnect;
104    exit;
```

Any idea why this happens?
I'd appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

> The transaction behaviour of the `disconnect` method is, sadly,
>   undefined. Some database systems (such as Oracle and Ingres) will
>   automatically commit any outstanding changes, but others (such as
>   Informix) will rollback any outstanding changes. Applications not
>   using `AutoCommit` should explicitly call `commit` or `rollback` before
>   calling disconnect.

See https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#disconnect

Comment: but in my script , I have add   $dbh->do("COMMIT") or die "$dbh->errstr"; before disconnect

Comment: can you try using `begin_work`, `commit` and `rollback` methods for transaction management, instead of doing them with raw SQL?